# Do multiple docker filter options perform a local AND or OR operation?

Tags: docker

I am trying to perform a `prune` operation with multiple filters. This is covered in the [docs here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/#filtering):

> The filtering flag (--filter) format is of “key=value”. If there is more than one filter, then pass multiple flags (e.g., --filter "foo=bar" --filter "bif=baz")

The docs fail to mention if using multiple filters like this combining them using a logical `AND` or `OR` operation.

I would like it to be an `AND` operation so that I can do something like this:

```
docker image prune --all --force --filter="label=com.company.product=myproduct" \
    --filter="label!=com.company.project=proj2"
```

and a Dockerfile with the following labels would not be pruned:

```
LABEL com.company.product="myproduct" com.company.project="proj2"
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Short answer

It's an `AND`.

### Testing it...

3 `Dockerfiles`:

```
FROM alpine
LABEL apples="fruit"

FROM alpine
LABEL oranges="fruit"

FROM alpine
LABEL apples="fruit" oranges="fruit"
```

3 `images`:

```
$ docker image ls 
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
both                latest              e9e48f31222f        11 seconds ago      4.41MB
oranges             latest              f384e4db9974        33 seconds ago      4.41MB
apples              latest              06fa8c565ec1        51 seconds ago      4.41MB
```

`--filter` tests follow*:

```
$ docker image ls --filter label=apples=fruit
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED              SIZE
both                latest              e9e48f31222f        34 seconds ago       4.41MB
apples              latest              06fa8c565ec1        About a minute ago   4.41MB

$ docker image ls --filter label=oranges=fruit
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED              SIZE
both                latest              e9e48f31222f        44 seconds ago       4.41MB
oranges             latest              f384e4db9974        About a minute ago   4.41MB

$ docker image ls --filter label=apples=fruit --filter label=oranges=fruit
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED              SIZE
both                latest              e9e48f31222f        About a minute ago   4.41MB
```

#### Prune

The image named `both` (which has both labels) is deleted:

```
$ docker image prune -a --filter label=apples=fruit --filter label=oranges=fruit
WARNING! This will remove all images without at least one container associated to them.
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
Deleted Images:
untagged: both:latest
deleted: sha256:e9e48f31222f04dd54cffb4688367338d8e061ef3b1471768c1ef6a7045007ab
```

---

* Notice: `docker image ls` doesn't work with **negative filtering** (`!=`), from the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/#filtering):

> **Predicting what will be removed**
>
> If you are using positive filtering (testing for the existence of a label or that a label has a specific value), you can use `docker image ls` with the same filtering syntax to see which images match your filter.
>
> However, if you are using negative filtering (testing for the absence of a label or that a label does *not* have a specific value), this type of filter does not work with `docker image ls` so you cannot easily predict which images will be removed. In addition, the confirmation prompt for `docker image prune` always warns that *all* dangling images will be removed, even if you are using `--filter`.

Answer (score 1):

[tgogo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53085137) is pretty spot on expect for when using multiple negated label filters which are instead ORed together. This is undocumented and I believe it should not work this way so I have submitted an [issue about this](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/40286) but for those wanting this functionality now:

```sh
bash -c '{ docker ps -aq --filter "status=exited" && docker ps -aq --filter "label=foo" && docker ps -aq --filter "label=bar"; }' | sort | uniq -u | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rm
```

Add or remove `&& docker ps -aq --filter "label=<label exclude from pruning>"` in the command to add or remove negated label filters. Other non-negated filters should be added to the first instance of `docker ps` (eg `docker ps -aq --filter "status=exited" --filter "until=24h"`). `bash -c` is only necessary for users of shells which don't support the bash specific syntax used above (like fish).